# Spork error: undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork

Any idea what would cause this? It's been working for months until today. Not sure what I changed.

I have the spork 0.9.0.rc9 gem on my machine (OS X 10.7 up to date with all os updates) and in my Gemfile (Rails 3.1.1). When I try to run spork --bootstrap I get the following error:

```
undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:10:in 'initialize'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:25:in 'new'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:25:in 'block in latest_load_paths'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:24:in 'each'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:24:in 'inject'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/gem_helpers.rb:24:in 'latest_load_paths'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork.rb:108:in 'other_spork_gem_load_paths'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork.rb:101:in 'detect_and_require'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:167:in ''
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:49:in 'find_test_framework'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:57:in 'run'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in 'run'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/bin/spork:10:in ''
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/bin/spork:19:in 'load'
/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p190/bin/spork:19:in ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem. It was throwing me

"NoMethodError: undefined method `query_options' for nil:NilClass

You should move your

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

to

```
Spork.each_run do

end
```

That should fix the issue.